# Have system prioritize the use of alias over binary on Linux shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am currently working on a project for my university in Java. The project needs to run on a specific server that my university provides that runs CentOS Linux. It also needs to be run by shell scripts provided by my professor, which I am not allowed to modify. The shell scripts are in the following format:
scenario.sh

```
node 0 100 2 "this is a message from 0" 30 1 &
node 1 100 2 "this is a message from 1" 30 2 &
node 2 100 2 1 &
```

The shell script is simply running 3 copies of my program with its required command line arguments. Therefore "node" needs to be the name of the executable file/alias so that the shell script can execute it. Since my program is in java, and java needs the "java" command to run the program, I set `alias node='java node'`. For clarity the commands I put in the terminal, in order, are:

```
> javac Node.java
> alias node='java Node'
> sh scenario.sh
```

I developed and successfully ran the program on another server that is designated for development. However, when I try to run the program on the testing server, it fails. I found that the issue is that the testing server has Node.js installed, which is run with the command "node". Thus, when I run the shell script, it attempts to run Node.js instead of my Java program. Since it is a university-owned server I cannot uninstall Node.js and do not have sudo/root access. Is there any command I can use to make the system prioritize running the alias instead of Node.js? If not, are there any other ways I can get around this?

I tried running each command from the shell script in the terminal instead, and that works properly. I assume that means the terminal prioritizes aliases before command binaries while shell scripts do not. Regardless, this is not an acceptable solution because the project requires that the program is run from the shell script.
I've also looked through stack overflow and other websites for a solution, but all seem to involve using sudo. I do not have sudo permissions on the testing server.

Comment: **Aliases are not passed to a separate shell.** When you run the script with `sh scenario.sh` or just `./scenario.sh` it creates a new shell which _never_ uses any alias(es) set in the parent. If you instead do `source scenario.sh` or `. scenario.sh` it executes _in_ the original/parent shell, with the alias(es) having first 'priority'. Alternatively a shell function can be passed from bash to bash, but only in some versions and/or systems due to a past security flaw; in any shell an executable file (i.e. another script) in a directory that is early in your `$PATH` will have 'priority'.

Comment: Add a shell script `node` to a directory on your PATH that contains a shebang line (`#!/bin/sh`) and `exec java Node "$@"` which executes your program.

Comment: Child processes inherit environment variables. In some shells, you can even kind of inherit shell functions to a child process which is a shell of the same kind. I am not aware of a shell which has defined a similar mechanism for alias. The main reason is probably that virtually nobody uses aliases in a shell script. bash in particular has by default turned off alias expansion in script, so you would have to turn this on explicitly anyway.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to modify the shell script to explicitly use the full path to the Java executable instead of relying on the "node" alias. You can find the full path to the Java executable by running the command "which java" on the testing server. Then, replace "node" with the full path in the shell script.

For example, if the output of "which java" is "/usr/bin/java", you can modify the shell script as follows:

```
/usr/bin/java Node 0 100 2 "this is a message from 0" 30 1 &
/usr/bin/java Node 1 100 2 "this is a message from 1" 30 2 &
/usr/bin/java Node 2 100 2 1 &
```

This should ensure that the Java executable is used instead of Node.js.

If modifying the shell script is not an option, you can try renaming your Java executable from "node" to something else, such as "my_node", and update the shell script to use the new name. This should prevent any conflicts with Node.js.

Alternatively, you can try setting the PATH environment variable in the shell script to include the directory containing your Java executable before the directory containing the Node.js executable. For example

```
export PATH=/path/to/java/bin:$PATH
java Node 0 100 2 "this is a message from 0" 30 1 &
java Node 1 100 2 "this is a message from 1" 30 2 &
java Node 2 100 2 1 &
```

This should ensure that the Java executable is found and used first.

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently acceptable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).